# Associate a File Type with my iOS App: No Image for file

Tags: ios, iphone, file-import

I associated a custom file-type with my iphone-app and everything works fine: When selecting a file in mail it asks me to open that file with my app.

But, it only shows a default image for that file and not my provided 22x29px PNG.

Can you see my mistake?

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>DocIcon.png</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>kmk custom data type</string>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.mycomp.document.kmk</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
...
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.text</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>My App File</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.mycomp.document.kmk</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <string>kmk</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

The docIcon.png is 22x29px and has a retina-brother in 44x58px called docIcon@2x.png, but thats not referenced anywhere. I think this could be the error, but I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Xcode 5, select your "TARGET", go to tab "INFO", Have a look in "Document Types" : Did you set your icon here ? Now, check if in exported / imported UTI you set the identifiers = the Type you put in "Document Types".

especially check :

com.mycomp.document.**kmk** != com.mycomp.document.**kpk**

edit : (removed)

edit 2 :

Based on apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW8)

you should set Exported UTIs :

> identifier = com.mycomp.document.kmk
>
> conform to = public.data
>
> Additional exported UTI properties
>
> UTTypeTagSpecification (Dictionary)
>
> ```
>   public.mime-type = Application/XXX    (replace XXX vita your app name)
>   public.filename-extension = kmk       (extension without the dot)
> ```

you'll found that in your info.plist at UTExportedTypeDeclarations

```
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>YOUR DESCRIPTION</string>             (to be changed)
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.mycomp.document.kmk</string>
        <key>UTTypeSize320IconFile</key>
        <string>Icon@2x</string>
        <key>UTTypeSize64IconFile</key>
        <string>Icon</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>kmk</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>Application/YOUR-APP-NAME</string>  (to be changed)
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Edit 3 :

netshark1000 have report that Application/YOUR-APP-NAME have solve the issue.

Hop this can help others.

Comment: there is no image set. I can select my images with the + Button, but XCode doesn't do anything. The images don't get added after selection. The kpk !=kmk error was just a copy and paste error. It is the same - I changed it for privacy reasons

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Perhaps wrong mime type? I create the file with mimetype "application/json". The definition above says "public.txt". The icon within mail looks like a textfile. The content of my file is zipped json

Comment: I think I've found ! (based on your remark on mime type). I'll post un update

Comment: Thank you very much! What it finally fixed was setting the mimetype to application/MyAppName while creating the file. Could add this to your answer to help others?